# Nasty crease where I joined two meshes together

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to sculpt what I thought would be a simple [Q*Bert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert) model. I started with a sphere for the body and a cylinder for the long nose. After joining them together I'm stuck with a noticeable crease where the face and nose meet. I have been unable to smooth that out. Any attempt to sculpt in that area amplifies the crease.
I have tried turning on auto merge, selecting vertices along the crease and pressing <kbd>G</kbd> (in *Edit Mode*) to try to eliminate the crease without success.

[image]

How can I fix this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfVTy.jpg)

Comment: If the boolean join was made correctly, you should be able to round the crease by sculptin with dynamic topology enabled. Did you tried that?

Comment: a last resort would be to remesh the whole mesh

Comment: Thanks. I ended up starting over and simply extruding the nose and legs from the sphere instead of using cylinders.

Comment: How come your model is triangulated if you started from scratch? It should be [quad-based topology](https://resources.turbosquid.com/training/modeling/quad-based-topology/) or else it will always be messy. I think you used Icosphere? don't use that. Use a cube and turn it into a sphere like here https://youtu.be/bCvWrFcUiRU?t=23

Comment: Do you use [Dyntopo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/dyntopo.html)? It triangulates the mesh and creates areas with a different mesh density as we can see in the screenshots. That's totally fine for sculpting but not for animation & texturing. If you join 2 objects with Ctrl+J they will become 1 object with 2 separate meshes. The meshes can only be sculpted individually and don't merge -> the crease persists. As already suggested, you need either boolean them & touch the mesh with Dyntopo enabled to create the vertices -or- use the voxel remesher.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I actually ended up starting over and just extruding the node and legs from the sphere instead of joining cylinders.